# Kotlin, Observable.zip - не возвращает никаких значений

Tags: android, kotlin, rxjava

Доброе утро!
Решил я оптимизировать свое приложение, и объединил 3 запроса в zip-пакет. Ранее делал это на java, но попробовав на Kotlin столкнулся с проблемами. Приложение собирается, передаваемые в запросы параметры не нулевые, сами запросы по одиночке работают (пользователь так точно существует, и вятигвается, два других запроса свежие, их я по одиночке не проверял), а вместе ничего ничего не возвращают. Привожу участок кода:

```
        Observable.zip(firebase.fetchUserById(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
            firebase.fetchAssociates(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
            firebase.fetchPomodoro(auth.currentUser?.uid!!))
            { user, associates, pomodoro ->

                println("bbbbbbbbbbb")
            }
```

Так вот это "bbbb" никогда не выведется.

Сами запросы у меня такие:

```
fun fetchUserById(userId: String): Observable<User> {
    return RxFirebaseDatabase
            .observeSingleValueEvent(database.child(USERS).child(userId), User::class.java)
}

fun fetchAssociates(userId: String): Observable<Associates> {
    return RxFirebaseDatabase
            .observeSingleValueEvent(database.child(ASSOCIATES).child(userId), Associates::class.java)
}

fun fetchPomodoro(userId: String): Observable<Pomodoro> {
    return RxFirebaseDatabase
            .observeSingleValueEvent(database.child(POMODORO).child(userId), Pomodoro::class.java)
}
```

Котлиновский плагин обновлен до последней версии. Три часа убито на поиск ошибки, в итоге я тут. Подскажите, что не так написано?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
А если напрямую спросить:

```
    firebase.fetchUserById(auth.currentUser?.uid!!).subscribe{
        user ->
        println("777777777" + user.getId())
    }
```

то все работает! Но мне-то нужен оптимизированный запрос!

Comment: Пишите на Java. Потом Code > Convert Java Code to Kotlin Code

Comment: После zip subscribe вызывается?

Comment: Я просто хочу разобраться. И в дальнейшем писать только на котлине) Но попробую сделать через конвертацию. subscribe не вызывается, там вообще ничего почти нельзя вызвать.

Comment: Возможно дело в том, что вы ничего не возвращаете из лямбды. Попробуйте что-то вернуть. Например так: `{ user, associates, pomodoro ->  println("bbbbbbbbbbb"); Triple(user, associates, pomodoro); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Господа, на свежую голову мне таки удалось найти решение. Поиграв немного со скобами и опциями, я смог дописать subscribe(). Как оказалось, при компиляции запросы без подвешенного обработчика просто не отправляются, поэтому наличие subscribe() обязательно! В итоге я получил следующее:

```
    Observable.zip(firebase.fetchUserById(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
            firebase.fetchAssociates(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),
            firebase.fetchPomodoro(auth.currentUser?.uid!!),{user, associates, pomodoro ->
        println("000000000000000002")

        user
    }).subscribe({
        println("000000000000000003  " + it.getName())
    })
```